# Preserving Anonymity on Jobs?

Tags: feature-request, jobs

All things considered I'd rather like to keep my online and real-life identities separate. However I also rather need a new job.

Is it possible or reasonable to maintain anonymity with a CV on jobs.stackoverflow.com? (I guess this is a feature-request if not)

Comment: I don't think the edit is valid - I was tagging for the jobs site not the subject matter of careers

Comment: Erm, isn't the "jobs" site called careers? http://careers.stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Ah, I see the old one is still there: http://jobs.stackoverflow.com/ I'm betting that goes away RSN.

Comment: Jobs is used by employees to find companies who are hiring. Careers is for companies to look for employees who are looking for new work.

Comment: I don't think that's true, Bob. I think it's more like: Careers is intended for both. Jobs is something which was moved from Joel's site to SO a while ago and is unrelated. This town ain't big enough for the two of 'em.

Answer (score 3):

AFAIK, you don't *have* to link your SO profile. Granted, that's kinda the hook for SOC, but it's still not really known if employers will really *care* - you could always try going without it for a few months & see how that pans out.

Frankly, I'm fine with linking the two so long as it's not exposed to casual browsing / Google / etc. What I *don't* want is any indication on SO-proper that I have a CV posted on SOC - right now, that's the case, and I hope it stays that way.

Answer (score 0):

1. You can choose not to associate your SO account with your CV.
2. You can choose not to make your CV public to the world (it is private by default).
3. If you pay to file your CV, and make it searchable by employers, only potential employers will see it.

If you choose only #3, I *do* recommend associating your SO account with your CV -- since there's benefit to you, and the audience is rather small (potential employers only). I can't think of any negatives. #2 is what you probably want to avoid.

Comment: #2 is definitely to be avoided :) I'd still prefer to have my CV labelled "annakata" only (losing the SO account clearly loses the hook) but possibly this is for paranoid, OCD-based reasons, not worth your development time.